# Facebook Credits Invalid State Transition Error

Tags: facebook, credits

I am using Github sample code for the Facebook Credits (callback.php and index.php) but its giving me the below error.. anybody have any solution???

"Order::update_order called with invalid state transition:3 -> 0"

Thanks..

Answer (score 0):

Hard to answer without seeing the code you're using, but the response you send should look like this:

```
{
 "method": "payments_status_update", 
 "content": {
        "order_id": ORDER_ID, 
        "status": "settled"
        }
}
```

`ORDER_ID` should be replaced by the order id sent from fB with the request.

There were incorrect examples out there that showed:

```
{
 "method": "payments_status_update", 
 "content": [{
        "order_id": ORDER_ID, 
        "status": "settled"
        }]
}
```

but the second one doesn't work.  Check to make sure you're not sending content as an array.